# NSMenu cancelTracking sometimes doesn't cancel tracking

Tags: nsview, nsmenuitem, nsmenu

I have a QT app, and I'm using native menus on OSX.  I have custom-drawn menu items, which I created by attaching my own NSView-derived class to the NSMenuItems that I want to draw specially.  This all works fine;  the menu items draw right and activate the menu function correctly.  However, after activating the menu function, the menu doesn't go away -- it's still tracking the mouse movement. (The cursor still highlights items) I've spent days googling for answers, and I haven't seen a similar problem elsewhere.  My NSView class is simple;  I've overridden the "rect" class for drawing, and my mouseUp event is here:

```
-(void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSMenuItem* item = [self enclosingMenuItem];
    if ( item != nil ){
        NSMenu *menu = [item menu];
        if ( menu != nil ){
            [menu cancelTracking];
            [NSApp sendAction:[item action] to:[item target] from:item];
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried using "cancelTrackingWithoutAnimation", and I've tried calling cancelTracking on the parent menuBar.  Can anyone tell me under what circumstances "cancelTracking" might fail?  I'm not sure what to try next.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its too late but I also faced the same issue and fixed it by using carbon API `CancelMenuTracking(),`

```
CancelMenuTracking(
  MenuRef   inRootMenu,
  Boolean   inImmediate,
  UInt32    inDismissalReason)
```

Used `_NSGetCarbonMenu` to get the menuref of NSMenu.

```
menuRef = _NSGetCarbonMenu(myMenu);
```

`CancelMenuTracking(menuRef,YES,kHIMenuDismissedByCancelMenuTracking)`; for 10.5 and `CancelMenuTracking(menuRef,YES,0)`; for 10.6 and above